# Flutter not picking up firebase logout

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement Firebase Authorization in Flutter. I am able to login and navigate to a new screen successfully, however when trying to logout, i am seeing activity in logcat indicating:

[image: Logcat event for firebase signout]

However I am expecting the homepage to update based on this logout. That is, I have an icon which should toggle between login and logout but the app seems to stay as logged in. These are the layout changes i am expecting which appear on the same screen:

[image: Loggedin screen]

User clicks the logout button but I am expecting the widget to update to the following:

[image: Logged Out Screen]

My function that I am calling for the signout is as follows and appears inside my homepage widget

```
class _MainActivityState extends State<MainActivity> {

        var  userStatus = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();


  Future logout()
  async{
     final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
     await auth.signOut();
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainActivity())
);


    return userStatus = null;
}
```

Further down in my code I am using an `if` statement (which works if i manually override login/logout with a string)to toggle between widgets based on userStatus as follows:

```
if(userStatus != null)
                  Container(
//Some code here for the widget showing login button.
)
```

or if logged out:

```
if(userStatus == null)
                  Container(
//Some code here for the widget showing login button
 )
```

I have a separate Login page where I initially performed the login but the Auth status seems to be persisting for the entire app.

How to I override as it seems the `Auth.signout()` is not updating the users status.

Comment: consider using any state management technique like MobX, so you can make your UI reactive to changes like logging out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a problem with you setting your variable to `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();` which returns a Future, but not awaiting the value before building your widget. Because of this it will not be null, but a Future state waiting to complete so your condition will never evaluate the null correctly.

To fix this lets initialize userStatus in an initState method so it is only initialized once with an async function to rebuild after the Future completes. Then in your logout method just call this function to reset userStatus and rebuild the widget with setState:

```
var userStatus;
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setUserStatus();
}

Future<void> setUserStatus() async {
  userStatus = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  setState(() {});
}

Future<void> logout() async {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  setUserStatus();
}
```

Comment: what other code would you like to see? i tried the setState inside the Future function and it does not address the issue. the logout request seem to go to firebase but what happens is the device still shows as being logged in if you close the app and open it again.

Comment: I just updated my post, try this solution and see if it works, as for closing the app and opening it and it still being logged in, I dont think it is actually the user being logged in still, but since you are setting the variable to a Future value and checking if it is null to show logged out UI, it will never evaluate as null when you build

Comment: where does the `getUserStatus()` function get used?

Comment: Woops, that was a typo on my part. It should be setUserStatus

Comment: Essentially, setUserStatus waits for the currentUser() function to complete before setting userStatus, and then we call an empty setState so the widget rebuilds.

Comment: Thanks, sort of works. there are a few issues with how i want the thing to work but I think that could be considered a separate question e.g. pressing logout changes the widget. but when navigating from login page back to main page (after login) is still shows the login widget. thanks for the help

Comment: Yea, that is because the variable you are using is initialized as null so itll show the login widget upon first build. This is why I would recommend using a FutureBuilder with the Future being the result of currentUser() so you are building your page on if the user is logged in or not. This approach was just a solution to what you had posted so far. With a full build method I could probably show an example of how to change it to a FutureBuilder

Comment: Thanks, will investigate

Answer (score 0):

After you log out using this code:

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
await auth.signOut();
```

Why would you navigate to the same Activity(screen)? Just rebuild the screen again using setState and assign the new userStatus there:

```
setState(() { userStatus = null; });
```

Comment: I was playing around with options to see if it would resolve. do I put the `setState` immediately after the `await auth.signout` line?

Comment: I tried the solution, but what is happening is that the screen renders the logout widget for a brief moment (0.5 second) and then reverts back to the logged in widget.

Comment: Yes after a successful log out call the `setState` function and put inside its callback `userStatus = null;` which will be called before rebuilding. Before the rebuilding of the UI the `userStatus ` will be null so it should show the logout button.

Comment: I don't know why your logout widget renders only briefly. You have to share more code. Do you have a timer or something?

Comment: which other code would you like to see. Let me know and I will update teh question? i don't have a timer. but once logged out why would it run the widget for the view where the user is still logged in?